# python setup.py install without sudo

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, permission-denied, setup.py

I have a project with some structure, it is console script. The project has `setup.py` file.

All I want is to install my package any way without using sudo.
I spent like 10 hours browsing the internet and can't find a working solution.

I keep getting error: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'srm.egg-info/PKG-INFO' if using virtualenv`

And getting `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-27105.write-test'`

It works good enough with sudo(but there are troubles with uninstall, and it is still not working with virtualenv)

Using: Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7,

Comment: What's wrong with **virtualenv**? Can you explain? How do you use it? Is it activated? Which version of **pip** (and **setuptools**)?

Comment: I already understood the root of the problem, added it in the answer section below. What was wrong with virtualenv is that it was behaving like it is working with absolute path when I tried to install my program and it confused me. But now it all works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the parameter --user to specify your home directory:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: I already tried it. It gives the same error:
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'srm.egg-info/PKG-INFO'

Comment: This worked for me. I couldn't install xgboost from source using python (`python setup.py install`) because the python script didn't have permission to create a folder. If I tried installing with sudo, python returned `ImportError: No module named setuptools`, even though I have setuptools installed. Specifying the flag --user and running install without sudo solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so I f***ed up so much:

After using sudo, package files were created in the location of my setup.py and they had lock icon (system files because of sudo) and I could no longer install program without sudo.

My solution was to sudo rm -r all of the previously created locked files in program directory and those near python directory, and just install my program without sudo using --user or virtualenv.

Comment: So easily done, I did exactly the same thing. You've just saved me a load of time - thanks!